# Disable/deny report subscriptions on single SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

Is it possible to enable/disable SSRS report subscriptions on a report by report basis?

I have a particular report which has been identified as causing excess load on the database when it is scheduled to run every 15 minutes. Whilst the report is being optimised I'd like to deny the ability for all users to schedule this particular report without impacting any other reports subscriptions.

Alternatively is there a way to limit the frequency a report can be scheduled (eg: no more frequently than daily), again on a report by report basis?

SSRS 2012 in native mode.

Comment: if you remove access to all users until the issue is fixed, it should solve the issue. otherwise just disable the subscription until further changes or create a new subscription for that specific report that should run less often? I don't see this as a big issue at all. what is the catch?

Comment: thanks Viking.  We still need users to be able to execute the report ad-hoc, just not schedule it (or at least limit the available schedule frequency to daily). In the mean time I am creating a job that returns all subscriptions that are scheduled hourly or more frequently so we can notify the user or manually delete the subscription and will potentially add on a step to delete those subscriptions automatically.

Comment: Good luck with that!